# Request_UnsupportedQuery while trying to get list of specific users

Tags: powershell, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I'm using PowerShell to connect to Azure AD. I need to get a list of specific users whose accounts are not in a particular team.

To enter my tenant, I used cmdlet `Connect-AzureAD`. To get users I have to use the cmdlet `Get-AzureADUser`. I'm using `-Filter` along with it to get a list of those specific users.

I'm using a cmdlet like this:

> Get-AzureADUser -Filter "Team ne 'Development' "

But I'm getting an error like  this:

> Get-AzureADUser : Error occured while executing GetUsers
>
> Code: Request_UnsupportedQuery
>
> HttpStatusCode : BadRequest
>
> HttpStatusDescription: BadRequest
>
> HttpResponseStatus: Completed

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested in my environment. I also got same error.

[image: error]

This error usually occurs because depending on PowerShell version, **Get-AzureADUser** won’t support `ne`(not equal to) operator and `Team` attribute with `Filter` statement.

Instead of `Team` attribute, you can make use of `Department`.

Only the following operators are supported by **`Get-AzureADUser filter`** parameter based on version.

- eq  - equals to
- and - including both
- or - either first or second
- startswith - String starts with

To filter the list of users by `eq` operator worked.

> Get-AzureADUser -Filter "Department eq 'IT"

The output will be like this:

[image]

Please check below workarounds if they are helpful.

- You can try using `and` operator by including all departments other than "Development".
- Otherwise, you can update the versions and try again.